Disqus Integration Not Working in Docusaurus Blog Post After Swizzling
I followed this guide to integrate Disqus comments into my Docusaurus blog. After swizzling, my BlogPostItem component looks like this:
import React from 'react'
import { DiscussionEmbed } from 'disqus-react'
import { useBlogPost } from '@docusaurus/theme-common/internal'
import BlogPostItem from '@theme-original/BlogPostItem'

export default function BlogPostItemWrapper(props) {
  const { metadata } = useBlogPost()
  const { frontMatter, permalink, title } = metadata
  const { comments = true } = frontMatter
  console.log(metadata)


  return (
    <>
      <BlogPostItem {...props} />
      {comments && (
        <DiscussionEmbed
          shortname='https-replica-io-dev-1'
          config={{
            url: permalink,
            identifier: permalink,
            title,
            language: 'en_US',
          }}
        />
      )}
    </>
  )
}

However, the comment section is not working as expected. It displays the following error:
We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide.

In the browser console, I see these errors:
Error: Script error for "translations", needed by: core/strings
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
GET https://referrer.disqus.com/juggler/stat.gif?event=failed_embed.server.15 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
Image
e @ embed.js:49
frame:fail @ embed.js:50
m @ embed.js:49
trigger @ embed.js:49
(anonymous) @ embed.js:49
m @ embed.js:49
trigger @ embed.js:49
(anonymous) @ embed.js:49

Refused to frame 'https://help.disqus.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://intercomrades.support https://intercom.skilljar.com https://academy.intercom.com https://academy.guests.intercom.com https://app.intercom.com https://app.eu.intercom.com https://app.au.intercom.com https://intercomrades.intercom.com https://intercomrades.eu.intercom.com https://intercomrades.au.intercom.com".

Things I've Checked

Verified that the shortname is correct.

Ensured that the permalink, identifier, and title are being passed correctly.


I expected a comment section in the blog post on my Docusaurus website.
